# Challenge: unable to logout of linux

Tags: linux, logout

I'm currently doing a challenge where I am suppose to break out of a Linux box.
The user for this box isn't part of the sudo group and I can't add this myself to the sudo group nor can I exit, logout, or quit.
I can't su because I don't know the password for other accounts on this box.
Do any of you guys have any ideas of how to get out?

Comment: Why can't you log out? What prevents you from typing `exit`, or what happens when you type `exit`?

Comment: What would be the benefit of exiting the current shell, with regards to your challenge?

Answer (score 1):

1. type `exit`
2. Press `Ctrl + D`
3. `kill` or `kill -9 your_shell_PID`
4. `poweroff` which will technically log you out
5. Unplug from the mains
6. Blow it all up
7. Cut all the wires